# System.InvalidOperationException: 'No Content found for ShellContent, Title:, Route D_FAULT_ShellContent2'

Tags: c#, maui

I am developing a MAUI application for Android and tried to speed up development of previously missing settings area by opening SettingsPage on application launch. Previously, I could navigate indirectly to SettingsPage, but now I receive the following exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'No Content found for ShellContent, Title:, Route D_FAULT_ShellContent2'
```

The app works fine if I change the startup page to the original one. 
So, this works `Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(DashboardPage))`, 
but this doesn't `Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(SettingsPage))`. 
This code is found in `App` constructor.

I do have the following code in `AppShell.xaml`:

```
<ShellContent
    Icon="apps"
    ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate view:SettingsPage}"
    Route="SettingsPage"/>
```

How can I get rid of the exception? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shell routing is not very intuitive, so have a look over [.NET MAUI Shell navigation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation) and do some hands-on experiments. The key take-away from the documentation is: When a route from the Shell visual hierarchy is navigated to, a navigation stack isn't created. However, when a page that's not in the Shell visual hierarchy is navigated to, a navigation stack is created.

To keep the answer short, routes defined in XAML work with preceding "//" so that they are absolute. The correct code to navigate to `SettingsPage` is:

```
Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//" + nameof(SettingsPage));
```

Also, note from the documentation: Global routes currently can't be the only page on the navigation stack. Therefore, absolute routing to global routes is unsupported. This means that the following code will fail:

```
Routing.RegisterRoute("monkeydetails", typeof(MonkeyDetailPage));
Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//monkeydetails");
```

Use relative navigation for global routes instead:

```
Shell.Current.GoToAsync("monkeydetails");
```